# How to get rid of the foriegn key exception in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a module in my project where in a functionality I have a textbox where I am entering a missing note and saving it with button, but the table where I am saving the data is having a foreign key and I am getting the following exception

My code is as follows

```
    public ActionResult SetBreakageNote(int id, string MissNote, int charge)
    {
        var Rdetail = new ReservationDetail();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Rdetail.ReservationID = id; 
            Rdetail.Description = MissNote;
            Rdetail.ChargeType = charge;
            db.Insert(Rdetail);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My View

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomTypeView>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<div class="col-3">
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="inventory my-1">
                                <textarea class="form-control breakage" placeholder="Enter Breakage Note" rows="1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default breakage" data-brid="@item.ReservationID"><i class="fa fa-file-invoice" style="color:red;"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

  $('.breakage').click(function () {
            $.post("@Url.Action("SetBreakageNote", "HouseKeeping")", { id: $(this).data('brid'), MissNote: $('.breakage').val(), charge: @((int)ChargeTypeEnum.Breakage) });
        });
```

Here is the exception I am getting

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ReservationDetails_Reservation". The conflict occurred in database "CavalaV3DB", table "dbo.Reservation", column 'ReservationID

ReservationID is a foreign key for Reservation table.

Please help me with this

Comment: so did pass `int id` with missing note text to your action method?

Comment: As far as I can see the database already contains a `ReservationDetail` with the id you are using and you only want to update the description. So maybe the right approach is to load the existing `ReservationDetail`, modify the description and perform an Update to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert some value into your `Rdetail` in `ReservationID` column. But that value is not there in `Reservation` table.
This is violating Foreign key constraint created in the `Rdetail` table.

You can avoid this by checking this before inserting data into the table

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           if(db.Reservation.where(a=>a.ReservationId==id).Amy()) //Condition to check if data is there or not
          {
            Rdetail.ReservationID = id; 
            Rdetail.Description = MissNote;
            Rdetail.ChargeType = charge;
            db.Insert(Rdetail);
            }
        }
```

Comment: but i have value in Reservation table with same ReservationID

Comment: Put you code in debug mode and check... public ActionResult SetBreakageNote(int id, string MissNote, int charge)...what are you getting in id, now again check if the reservation table if this id is exists or not. This is the only logical reason for getting foreign key exception.

Comment: in debug mode i am getting id as 0

Comment: If you inspect the Html code, does the `data-brid` attribute have a value different from 0?

Comment: @kunals, since the value is 0, not check in the other table if ReservationID is anywhere 0. I am sure there will not be any record.

Comment: @Vinod there is record with ReservationID

Comment: @kunals if `data-brid` is 0 you might not be providing the complete Model to the View since you're assigning the value from `item.ReservationId` and it has the value 0. If the `ReservationDetail` was properly loaded from database it should have an Id. Maybe you can check the Model you're providing to the view in debug mode.

Comment: @RogerSaladrigas ok i will check

Answer (score 0):

Before data can be inserted, the value in the `foreign key` field must exist in the other table first.You must build the table containing the `Primary Key` first after that you can populate them in a drop down from where you need to select first to save data.

> the best way to deal with `foreign key` in `other table's View` Bind them in a Drop Down List and set attribute required